# Регулярка, которая находит определенные пробелы

Tags: php, c#, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как будет выглядеть регулярка, которая найдет все пробелы кроме пробелов вокруг or и and ?

Пример:

"field = 10 and field2= 100 or field10 is not null"

регулярка не должна сработать на пробелы вокруг " and " и " or "

Comment: По поводу *field="1 or 2" and field=1* - а для какого языка? В C# - [`(?<="[^"]*?)\s(?=[^"]*")|(?<!\bor|\band)\s(?!or\b|and\b)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%3f)%5cs(%3f%3d%5b%5e%22%5d*%22)%7c(%3f%3c!%5cbor%7c%5cband)%5cs(%3f!or%5cb%7cand%5cb)&i=field+%3d+10+and+field2%3d+100+or+field10+is+not+null+field%3d%221+or+2%22+and+field%3d1).

Comment: Вам для какой цели нужно найти все пробелы? Чтобы удалить их потом или заменить на что-то?

Comment: Для удаление пробелов

Comment: @iluxa1810: Может, [`\s(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)|(?<!\bor|\band)\s(?!or\b|and\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/tU8zB4/1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам надо воспользоваться Lookahead и Lookbehind

```
(?<!or)(?<!and)\s(?!or)(?!and)
```

[**ДЕМО и объяснение**](https://www.regex101.com/r/jP9hZ5/1)

или чуть короче

```
(?<!or|and)\s(?!or|and)
```

**UPDATE** Чтобы не срабатывало на `horror andy hodor band`

```
 (?<!\bor|\band)\s(?!or\b|and\b)
```

[**ДЕМО**](https://www.regex101.com/r/jP9hZ5/5)

Comment: У меня не поймало пробел в `land of`.

Comment: @VladD пришлось сделать его менее красивым :)

Comment: А можно ли сделать, что бы те and и or, которые находятся в "" у них выделялись пробелы? Т.е например: field="1 or 2" and field=1 .

Comment: @iluxa1810 Наверное. все можно. но я не умею :(